# Custom format example for serial number creation in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, integer

I have recently switched over from OpenOffice Base to MySQL community. In ooBase you can customize integers upon entering them into the database. For example I could type 2013_00000 and then every number in this column would be formatted in this way (2013_00001, 2013_00002, ...). After playing around with MySQL community for a while I noticed that there is no obvious way to format a custom integer like this. I might be overlooking something basic, but if anyone knows how to do this please let me know. Thank you

Comment: Afaik, you'll need a trigger for that.

Comment: Do you have to *insert* formatted value, or do you need a way to format the value returned by your *select* statement?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux insert formatted value. It is currently just all integers, but I want to add the year as a prefix to the number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to manipulate data before inserting them you need a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html).

Something like that:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_sn BEFORE INSERT ON tbl
FOR EACH ROW
    SET NEW.sn = CONCAT(LEFT(NEW.sn, 4), '_', RIGHT(NEW.sn,5));
```

If you need to update your rows, you need a second trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_sn BEFORE UPDATE ON tbl
FOR EACH ROW
    SET NEW.sn = CONCAT(LEFT(NEW.sn, 4), '_', RIGHT(NEW.sn,5));
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01428/1 for the complete example.

Here, I use the `CONCAT()`, `LEFT()` and `RIGHT()` functions for simplicity. Maybe your data require more complex manipulations (i.e.: padding). MySQL has a rich set of [string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html). Anyway this is the principle.

Comment: I do, in fact, need to update. So when you say trigger on update you simply mean to write it in like this:  CREATE TRIGGER ON UPDATE ins_sn BEFORE INSERT ON tbl

Comment: @user2618927 I edited the answer (and the sqlfiddle demo) to demonstrate both `ON INSERT` and `ON UPDATE` triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most flexible (here locked down to an underscore separator), but you *can* do it with a trigger, something like this;

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER trig_MyTable BEFORE INSERT ON MyTable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT seq into @seq FROM MyTable_Seq FOR UPDATE;
  SET NEW.id = @seq, @cutoff = LOCATE('_', @Seq);
  UPDATE MyTable_Seq SET Seq = 
         CONCAT(LEFT(@seq, @cutoff), 
                LPAD(SUBSTR(@seq, @cutoff+1)+1, LENGTH(@seq)-@cutoff, '0')); 
END;
//
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/303a7/1).

Comment: Okay I understand the principle that you are using with this code. I was hoping for an easier point and click type solution but I will try to use a trigger. Thanks for the idea